# Button to go back to MainActivity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-button

I want to create a button that would lead the user straight back to main activity which doesn't have the android name="com.example.example".
It has android.intent.etc...
How can I reference my button to go back to this activity?

Comment: thanks for editing, (have bad english)

Comment: what is the full name of the Activity you are trying to start ?

Comment: Main Activity, hers is the <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Main" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: @Moussa The accepted answer is wrong since it will add a new instance of Home activity to the stack, it's like create your activity again and again!!

Comment: Ok zzzzzzzzzzzzz fixed the answer, thanks  for your help

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Lets say your main activity is called Main.java.

```
btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

  private void onClick(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, Main.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   
    startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

Comment: This will add a new instance of Home activity to the stack, not take the user back to the Home activity.

Comment: You are adding new instance to the stack!!

Comment: I added the flag so it doesn't add a new instance to the stack.

Answer (score 15):

use   `startActivity(intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));`

Comment: +1: This is the correct response.  Adding flags like NEW_TASK will only create unexpected behavior for the user, and simply starting a new activity will add a second (new) instance to the stack.

Comment: @Moussa Intent a = new Intent(this,Home.class);
        a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(a);

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes you can just call `activity.finish()` to end current activity, so the main (first created) activity will pop out.

If this is not your case, do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)             
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is my setup:    public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
              Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
                 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                         | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                 startActivity(intent);
               This is the error:  The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<Main>) is undefined'.

Comment: what is the name of the class that contains the onClick method

Comment: Thanks for your help very much but zzzzzzzzzz answer helped me

Answer (score 0):

Well from wherever you are just call startActivity() with the required parameters inside the buttons onClick method.  That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    finish();
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16343576)

Comment: @LunarWatcher I respectfully disagree - this _is_ an _attempt_ to answer... An attempt that is perhaps faulty and happens to work in very specific cases - but a solution being bad is not reason enough for deletion.

Comment: It is 5 years too late and wrong, but the key here is that it requires clarification if someone is new to ANdroid for an instance. What is this, where is it placed, etc

Comment: Its a nice hack