# Android: Terminate current activity and go back to MainActivity

Tags: android

I have two activities. The first (`MainActivity`) has a `FloatingActionButton`, which starts the second (`AddEntryActivity`) via Intent. After filling the form, the data should be sent via JSON (nested asyncTask class). The success of this asyncTask is evaluated by a method of `AddEntryActivity`. 

If it fails, it toasts a message. If it was successful, it toasts a message (everything works up to this point) and should close this activity and return to `MainActivity`.

I read a lot of similar questions like:

- [Android: Go back to previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity),
- [How to finish current activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000787/how-to-finish-current-activity-in-android),
- [Button to go back to MainActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460896/button-to-go-back-to-mainactivity)
- [android - How to close an activity on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473509/android-how-to-close-an-activity-on-button-click)

and tried with:

```
finish();
//super.finish();
//self.finish();
//AddEntryActivity.finish();
```

or

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
```

as well as combinations of them or this:

```
onBackPressed();
```

But none of them approach works for me. Here is the call of the second activity in the `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openAddRecordActivity();
        }
    });
}

public void openAddRecordActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddEntryActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The success toast appears (see below), but the return to the first activity never takes place. And here is the called method (by `onPostExecute()` of the AsyncTask) of `AddEntryActivity`:

```
    void processResult(String result) {
        if (result!=null) {

            String state = result.split("\\|")[0];
            String msg = result.split("\\|")[1];

            if (state == "200") {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Result!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
  }
```

I'm doing nothing fancy, but cannot see my mistake.
If you need additional information (like Manifest), let me know.

Comment: Can you try passing `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` while starting the `AddEntryActivity` and use `onBackPressed()` method once you get success response message?

Comment: If you started your second activity from the main, and you want to pass a result back, you should be using `startActivityForResult` first, then `setResult` and `finish` in the next

Comment: I think your code for `finish()` is never called. You should use `if ("200".equals(state))` and not the `==` operator, when it comes to strings.

Comment: A simple finish() should return you to the previous activity. You should not start the main activity again because that will put 2 main activities in your back stack. What happens after the success toast?  Does AddEntryActivity just stay on the screen?

Comment: Can you show AddEntryActivity fully?

Comment: @d4vidi It is called, since the toast with msg "OK" appears. I also verified this branch with a console output in Android Studio.

Comment: @GregMoens Yes, it simply stay as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class), 1010)` to go to SecondActivity then as soon as the AsyncTask is Successfull, just send the result to the MainActivity along with data like,

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("mydata", "myData");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

then in your MainActivity,

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 1010 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                //get your data from Intent
            }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, wow. It is working. Just for my curiosity: why is passing a result necessary? Normally, the first activity do not need any feedback. The toast message for the user would be enough.

Comment: @xentity thats completely optional, its just a way to tell the previous activity that the result is ok or not & according to that, you can cross check in the first Activity's onActivityResult(); method. Also if the answer helped you, please accept it! :)

Comment: Sure, I am supposed to accept this as a solution, but I am wondering, why my simple attempts did not work? In many other questions the solution was a simple finish() and I guess there is a more simple way.

Comment: @xentity that's because you were calling finish(); before calling startActivity();, due to this the Activity was killed & startActivity (); was never called!